# Getting backslash in REST POST request payload when reading data from Excel file

Tags: python, python-requests, http-post, openpyxl

I am trying to execute POST method using Python `requests` module. For this I am reading a data from an Excel file but when adding the data to a dictionary then I am getting backslash in request payload when submit to request.

**My Data in Excel file**

```
KEY - metadata
VALUE - {"key1" : "value1" , "key2" : "value2"}
```

**loaded data in a list like**

```
<class 'list'>
['metadata' : '{"key1" : "value1" , "key2" : "value2"}']
```

**Now reading and fetching the same in request_payload like**

```
    request_payload = "metadata" : [ 
                          getData["metadata"] 
                        ]
```

But the request submit to server is like

```
"metadata": ["{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}"]}
```

Simply, what I understand is that, when submitting request to server then a backslash (`\`) is added to double-quotes (`\"`).

Comment: Expected Output is like --

"metadata": [
    {
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2"
}
  ]

Comment: What is `getData`?

Comment: You might want to try https://jsonpickle.github.io/ - jsonpickle encode and decoding

Comment: `getData` iis pytest fixture method i created

Answer (score 0):

Yes , this is handled buy using python module `ast` .

```
import ast
json = ast.literal_eval("json_input")
```